# What are the best days to do fasting?

Tags: practice, fasting, sadhana

As a continuation to [this](https://hinduism.stackexchange.com/q/3207/65) question, What is the best day for fasting? As a techie I can comfortably fast only on weekends! So, can I do fasting on any day where I get less work? Are there any best days to fast?

**Edit** 
Am asking best day to fast only for understanding but not for evaluation.

Comment: I request the SE user to drop a comment for the reason behind voting for close!

Comment: I think fasting depends on the days ... For example, I've marked that people who stay angry, tensed generally fasts on Thursdays..

Comment: @Mr.Alien i never knew this finding! Do you mean people of different mental states observe fasting on different days? AFAIK, Thursday is Guru day & they fast for Sai Baba/ Raghavendra swami or on the name of their own guru!

Comment: Yea I mean am not sure whether this is somewhat related to astrology but a common practice amongst hindu is fasting on particular days matters, if you see, we usually fast on religious days, or eat once a day, hence in a way it is related to our mental states

Comment: Interesting! any ref?

Comment: I don't have one else would've answered, commented because I've heard this from elders

Comment: One of the day, yekadashi is known to be the best day for fasting because, it comes 5 days before full moon day/no moon day. The effect of moon is more on those days. Fasting 5 days before makes us being prepared for that day.

Comment: Do it on Ekadasi. Fasting is stipulated for this tithi.

Answer (score 2):

Your question is genuine but the problem is that as you said in weekends you are suggest to do fasting but in weekends you are doing nothing and not concentrate on any work and your mind is free to think anything and generally it happen  that whatever thing we wanted to do (like fasting) such conditions comes in which you are forced to cross it and negative energy (or mentality) force you to don't do that things that you wanted to do (as fasting).

And as per the Hinduism everyday in a week is dedicated to some of the God (as there are 33 Crore Lords in Hindu's) so **you can do fasting on any of the day in week** but personally I suggest you to **don't do fasting on weekend** as you are not able to concentrate on fasting and while you are working you are forcefully concentrate on your work the filling of hungriness will not come in your mind.

Comment: This seems like opinion only, you should cite some source to back up the answer. Also note that scientific speculations are not allowed.